# background и background-image не отображают изображение в div

Tags: html, css, background

background и background-image не отображают изображение в div, хотя они загружаются успешно то есть проблем с url нет.

Использую фреймворк django по этому в html с помощью шаблонизатора указываю в стилях относительный путь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div id="photo-album" 
style="background:url('{{ image.image.url }}');
background-size:cover;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в блоке нету контента, например текста или не задана высота, то естественно ничего не отобразиться. Ширина и так автоматически 100%, а вот высоты нет. Нужно задать физически задать высоту и всё отобразиться.

```html
<div id="photo-album" 
style="background:url('{{ image.image.url }}');
background-size:cover;
height: 500px;">
</div>
```

Comment: не помогло, height: 100% и в пикселях. а если в диве есть контент оно отображается.